# Trailing slashes on GETs cause 404 on Azure

Tags: azure, iis, servicestack

this is strange behaviour that has lost me days so putting it out there to see if anyone can shed any light.

I have a REST Api created in ServiceStack, which works fine:

```
api/tasks/overdue?assignedToTeam=Administration
```

This runs in Azure Websites fine for several days.  Then, without any changes or deployments, this rest call returns a 404.

At this point, if I use

```
 api/tasks/overdue/?assignedToTeam=Administration
```

It works.  (Note the trailing slash in front of the "?").  Only be re-deploying the SAME CODE, does it start working again.

Anyone come across this type of behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this happen, but I'd look at [enabling DebugMode](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#debugmode)` then add [?debug=requestinfo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#request-info) to your QueryString which should return the Debug Info for the Request and see if there's any difference in the Request ServiceStack gets before and after the 404.